# Async two-way communication with Windows Named Pipes (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, asynchronous, named-pipes

I have a windows service and a GUI that need to communicate with each other. Either can send messages at any time.

I'm looking at using NamedPipes, but it seems that you cant read & write to the stream at the same time (or at least I cant find any examples that cover this case).

Is it possible to do this kind of two-way communication via a single NamedPipe?
Or do I need to open two pipes (one from GUI->service and one from service->GUI)?

Comment: You could use WCF Duplex NamedPipes, I use this method for my Service/App communications, There is a nice example here that may help.http://tech.pro/tutorial/855/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using WCF you can use duplex named pipes

```
// Create a contract that can be used as a callback
public interface IMyCallbackService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void NotifyClient();
}

// Define your service contract and specify the callback contract
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IMyCallbackService))]
public interface ISimpleService
{
    [OperationContract]
    string ProcessData();
}
```

Implement the Service

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class SimpleService : ISimpleService
{
    public string ProcessData()
    {
        // Get a handle to the call back channel
        var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IMyCallbackService>();

        callback.NotifyClient();
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

Host the Service

```
class Server
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a service host with an named pipe endpoint
        using (var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SimpleService), new Uri("net.pipe://localhost")))
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISimpleService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "SimpleService");
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Simple Service Running...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            host.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Create the client application, in this example the Client class implements the call back contract.

```
class Client : IMyCallbackService
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Client().Run();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        // Consume the service
        var factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ISimpleService>(new InstanceContext(this), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/SimpleService"));
        var proxy = factory.CreateChannel();

        Console.WriteLine(proxy.ProcessData());
    }

    public void NotifyClient()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Notification from Server");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I've gone with this method, as it seems simpler than using 2 named pipes.

Comment: Any ideas I can get the windows service running fine but cannot find the service when trying to add service reference I get 'net.pipe://localhost/service1'.
There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d).

Answer (score 3):

Your named pipe stream classes (server or client) have to be constructed with a [`PipeDirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.pipedirection) of `InOut`.  You need one [`NamedPipeServerStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream), probably in your service, which can be shared by an arbitrary number of [`NamedPipeClientStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream) objects.  Construct the `NamedPipeServerStream` with the name of the pipe and the direction, and the `NamedPipeClientStream` with the name of the pipe, the name of the server, and the `PipeDirection`, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Using a single point to accumulate messages (a single pipe in this case) forces you to handle direction of the message yourself too (in addition to that you have to use a system-wide lock for the pipe).

So use 2 pipes with opposite directions.

(Another option would be using 2 MSMQ queues).