# Showing video from service application to user

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, named-pipes

This is a followup question to this one:
[Video frames send through Named Pipe very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49396277/video-frames-send-through-named-pipe-very-slow)

I think I might be going about this all wrong. The back-end video processing library that I'm using is written in .Net and has a number of functions that rely on Windows Forms. When used as a single desktop application the library's code is extremely fast and efficient. So I'm not worried about any performance on that end.

What I've been trying to do is separate the processing code from the UI. Technically I've succeeded, as I have an application that functions without a UI and takes command line parameters. The issue that I'm having is efficiently communicating between the service and UI. In a followup to my previous question linked to above, the communication between the service and UI is very sluggish, as least for displaying video.

```
var sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
// ** code to convert image to byte array ** //
Debug.Write(Environment.NewLine + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "\t");
sw.Reset();
sw.Start();
serverPipe.WriteBytes(byteImage);
Debug.Write(Environment.NewLine + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + "\t");
```

Here's the debug info (I have the FPS counter elsewhere, it shows the processing FPS). The first number is the time in milliseconds to convert the image to a byte array and the second number is the time to send the byte array through the named pipe:

```
51  131 
52  127 
43  131
FPS: 31
81  144 
40  119 
49  154 
53  140
FPS: 30
72  130 
42  130 
56  137 
48  131
FPS: 30
70  149 
34  137 
72  144 
44  126
FPS: 29
```

This roughly translates to about 2 to 4 FPS being shown in the UI application. I'm running the above code in its own thread and I block any new threads from being created while one is already active (the thread terminates as soon as the image is sent, this prevents any possibility of frames arriving out of order in the UI).

I'm thinking about 3 possible solutions:

1. Improve the efficiency of the named pipe code (unsure if possible)
2. Create a single application that can satisfy both a service (running as SYSTEM user) and a front-end UI when needed
3. Create an internal web component in the service to serve up a local page.

I'm not sure number 2 is possible as the application would need to run primarily as a system service that starts with the OS. It's a service that runs all the time regardless if a user is logged on. I'm not aware of a way to make a UI available to logged on users. In the past, I had accomplished something similar by relying on Session 0, which is not an option anymore (and very bad design).

Number 3 is likely my best choice as this is something that is on the road-map anyways, but I haven't tried to work this out yet on how to approach it. Creating the actual web-service portion is easy, the part I'm not sure about is how to serve each image as a frame of a continuous video displayed in the browser. Bandwidth is not a consideration as viewing the video stream is not all the time. Only once every so often to analyze or ensure the video processing is working correctly. Also all traffic will be local network only.

Comment: Is your image which you are transferring already compressed? How big is your buffer which you are writing into the stream? Perhaps it is to small?

Comment: The image is already a compressed bitmap. I'm not sure how big the buffer is, I'm using the code referenced in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478513/c-sharp-full-duplex-asynchronous-named-pipes-net