# Named Pipes not working for asynchronous duplex communication

Tags: c#, asynchronous, named-pipes, duplex

Somehow I am not able to get named pipes work for duplex communication between client and server for .Net app.
Duplex communication works fine when I go for sequential messaging, but when I make it random i.e., server and client can ping each other at any random time, it just doesn't work.

The other posts are not much helpful either - [c# Full Duplex Asynchronous Named Pipes .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478513/c-sharp-full-duplex-asynchronous-named-pipes-net)

I am attaching my code as below:

-Server code:

```
        namespace Server
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    var namedPipeServerStream = new NamedPipeServerStream("myPipe",
                        PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);
                    Task.Run(() => StartListeningAsync(namedPipeServerStream, (msg) => Console.WriteLine(msg)));
                    Task.Run(() => SendMessageAsync(namedPipeServerStream));
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }

                public static async Task SendMessageAsync(NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer)
                {
                    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(namedPipeServer))
                    {
                        while (true)
                        {
                            await Task.Delay(2000);
                            try
                            {
                                var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject($"Server {DateTime.Now}");
                                byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialized);
                                if (!namedPipeServer.IsConnected)
                                {
                                    namedPipeServer.WaitForConnection();
                                    Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
                                }
                                await namedPipeServer.WriteAsync(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
                                await namedPipeServer.FlushAsync();
                                namedPipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
                            }
                            catch (Exception exception)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Exception:{exception}");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                public static async Task StartListeningAsync(NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer, Action<string> messageRecieved)
                {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        try
                        {

                            StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            string messageChunk = string.Empty;
                            byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[1024];
                            do
                            {
                                if (!namedPipeServer.IsConnected)
                                {
                                    namedPipeServer.WaitForConnection();
                                    Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
                                }
                                await namedPipeServer.ReadAsync(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
                                messageChunk = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBuffer);
                                messageBuilder.Append(messageChunk);
                                messageBuffer = new byte[messageBuffer.Length];
                            } while (!namedPipeServer.IsMessageComplete);
                            if (messageRecieved != null)
                            {
                                messageRecieved(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(messageBuilder.ToString()));
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception exception)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Exception:{exception}");
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }
        }
```

Client code:

```
            namespace Client
            {
                class Program
                {
                    static void Main(string[] args)
                    {
                        var namedPipeClientStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "server", PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous,
                                            TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation);
                        Task.Run(() => StartListeningAsync(namedPipeClientStream, (msg) => Console.WriteLine(msg)));
                        Task.Run(() => SendMessageAsync(namedPipeClientStream));
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                    public static async Task SendMessageAsync(NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClient)
                    {
                        using (var stream = new StreamWriter(namedPipeClient))
                        {
                            while (true)
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    await Task.Delay(3000);
                                    var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject($"Client {DateTime.Now}");
                                    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serialized);
                                    if (!namedPipeClient.IsConnected)
                                    {
                                        namedPipeClient.Connect();
                                        namedPipeClient.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;
                                        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");
                                    }
                                    await namedPipeClient.WriteAsync(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
                                    await namedPipeClient.FlushAsync();
                                    namedPipeClient.WaitForPipeDrain();
                                }
                                catch (Exception exception)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Exception:{exception}");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    public static async Task StartListeningAsync(NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClient, Action<string> messageRecieved)
                    {
                        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(namedPipeClient))
                        {
                            while (true)
                            {
                                try
                                {

                                    StringBuilder messageBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                                    string messageChunk = string.Empty;
                                    byte[] messageBuffer = new byte[1024];
                                    do
                                    {
                                        if (!namedPipeClient.IsConnected)
                                        {
                                            namedPipeClient.Connect();
                                            namedPipeClient.ReadMode = PipeTransmissionMode.Message;
                                        }
                                        await namedPipeClient.ReadAsync(messageBuffer, 0, messageBuffer.Length);
                                        messageChunk = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(messageBuffer);
                                        messageBuilder.Append(messageChunk);
                                        messageBuffer = new byte[messageBuffer.Length];
                                    } while (!namedPipeClient.IsMessageComplete);
                                    if (messageRecieved != null)
                                    {
                                        messageRecieved(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(messageBuilder.ToString()));
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception exception)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Exception:{exception}");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Isn't `named pipes ` used for communication between process on the same machine?

Comment: @Legends It can also be different machines in the same local network. The first parameter of the `NamedPipeClientStream` constructor specifies the machine, with `.` being the local machine.

Comment: @ckuri : You are right.

 [read here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/choosing-a-transport)

_A named pipe has a name, and can be used for one-way or duplex communication between processes on a single machine._
and:
_The named pipe transport has very little reach; it can only connect to services running on the same machine._
and:
_Named pipes can be used to provide communication between processes on the same computer or between processes on different computers across a network._

Comment: Addition:
_If the server service is running, all named pipes are accessible remotely_

Comment: @Legends Your link is for WCF, so it could be that they are restricted to the local machine on WCF. Regular named pipes can be accessed from other machines, see _[Named pipes can be used for interprocess communication locally or over a network.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream(v=vs.110).aspx)_ and _[The name of the remote computer to connect to, or "." to specify the local computer.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb355390(v=vs.110).aspx)_

Comment: I read them, previously I thought that it is only for communication on a single computer, but it's also possible over local network... `Named pipes` is part of WCF

Comment: Unfortunately our comments don't answer his problem ;-)

Comment: Sorry guys...my bad ...I should have clearly specified both the processes are running on the same machine. For my own good, I just made this Demo app to simulate duplex communication using named pipes on the same machine, preferred to call one Client and the other Server :)