# How do I send and receive from my named pipe from outside the loop?

Tags: c#

From various examples, I have set up my named pipe loop like so:

```
NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer;

private void initPipeServer(string pipeName)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
    {
        pipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut);

        var threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        pipeServer.WaitForConnection();
        onNotify("Client connected on thread[{0}]", threadId);

        try
        {
            var pipeReader = new StreamReader(pipeServer);
            var pipeWriter = new StreamWriter(pipeServer);

            // how do I call and get a response from outside this loop?
            // var result = await pipeReader.ReadLineAsync();
            // await pipeWriter.WriteLineAsync("stuff");
            // LOOP HERE SOMEHOW WAITING FOR ASYNC MESSAGES AND RETURNING RESPONSE
            while (no body quits) 
            {
                let communication happen, when a hotkey is pressed in Host, it
                will use the named pipe to request and receive information from the client
            }


            pipeServer.Disconnect();
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            onNotify(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            pipeServer.Close();
            initPipeServer(pipeName);
        }
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

but how would I send and receive a response from outside the loop instead of just having a predetermined exchange?

**Update.** I think I'm looking for something like [Async two-way communication with Windows Named Pipes (.Net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432813/async-two-way-communication-with-windows-named-pipes-net) except I'm not using WCF and I'm not on a server. This is a WPF application.

**Update 2.** Ideal flow:

1. Host sets up named pipe server
2. Client connects to pipe server
3. When hotkey is pressed in Host, request is sent to client for information
4. Client returns information to Host
5. Proceed until either Host or Client quits, if Client quits, Host resets pipe server and waits for connection

Comment: There's no loop in your code

Comment: create a two separate tasks, the pipe will be a channel between them. What's the trigger for communication?

Comment: @Amit, yeah, let me add that

Comment: trigger for comm is essentially a hotkey, which will send a command through the named pipe to the other side, and the receive a response

Comment: reading http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/492231/Csharp-Async-Named-Pipes

Comment: I added the flow I am going for.

Comment: the codeproject project recreates the named pipe for each exchange - i don't think that is really necessary

Comment: another interesting link http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/using-named-pipes-to-connect-a-gui-to-a/231903148?pgno=2